# Count number of students with or without a passing grade in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create an application that allows the user to enter one letter grade (uppercase or lowercase) after another and continuously displays the number of students who passed (D or better) and the number who failed. Every time I enter a grade and click the button, it should count as either a fail or pass. For some reason, mine counts 1, then resets when I enter another one. How can I fix this? I've been searching for answers to my problem, but I've had no luck.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'declare variables
        Dim grade As String = 0
        Dim passNumber As Integer
        Dim failNumber As Integer
        'calculate
        grade = Me.txtGrade.Text
        If grade = "D" Or grade = "C" Or grade = "A" Or grade = "B" Or grade = "d" Or grade = "c" Or grade = "a" Or grade = "b" Then passNumber = passNumber + 1
        If grade = "F" Or grade = "f" Then failNumber = failNumber + 1
        'display message
        Me.lblFail.Text = failNumber
        Me.lblPass.Text = passNumber
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can I suggest that instead of `grade = Me.txtGrade.Text`, you use `grade = Me.txtGrade.Text.ToUpper`. There are two benefits - you'll be able to shorten your `If` statements to just check for upper-case letters, and later, if you decide to store each grade, they will all be upper-case instead of a mixture

Comment: Before anything else, turn on Option Strict for this project and all your projects.

Comment: Every time your code reaches `End Sub` `passNumber` an `failNumber` go out of scope and their values are forgotten.

Comment: `Dim grade As String = 0` Since grade is a string, it cannot have a value of 0. It can have a value of "0".

Answer (score 1):

Your passNumber and failNumber variables are local to the function call. Move them outside the method so that they are not reset every time the method is called:

```
Private passNumber As Integer
Private failNumber As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'declare variables
    Dim grade As String = 0

    'calculate
    grade = Me.txtGrade.Text
    If grade = "D" Or grade = "C" Or grade = "A" Or grade = "B" Or grade = "d" Or grade = "c" Or grade = "a" Or grade = "b" Then passNumber = passNumber + 1
    If grade = "F" Or grade = "f" Then failNumber = failNumber + 1
    'display message
    Me.lblFail.Text = failNumber
    Me.lblPass.Text = passNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As Meta has already pointed out the issue was the localization of the passNumber and failNumber variables.  I'd suggest also doing something like this to make the code more readable and maintainable.

```
Dim passNumber As Integer
Dim failNumber As Integer

Dim PassArray As String() = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
Dim FailArray As String() = {"f"}

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'declare variables
    Dim grade As String = Me.txtGrade.Text.ToLower()

    If PassArray.Contains(grade) Then
        passNumber += 1
    ElseIf FailArray.Contains(grade) Then
        failNumber += 1
    Else
        MsgBox("Error: Invalid Grade")
    End If

    'display message
    Me.lblFail.Text = failNumber
    Me.lblPass.Text = passNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but your code treats "D" as a failing grade, which is not what the OP states.

Comment: @Blackwood ah woops somehow I overlooked that initially.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Comments and explanations in-line.
**EDIT** Thanks to comment by @Blackwood. I have moved the passNumber and failNumber outside the method to the Form level (class level). This way they will retain there values between calls to the event.

```
Private passNumber As Integer
Private failNumber As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Using .ToUpper as suggested in Comments by David Wilson
    Dim grade = txtGrade.Text.ToUpper()
    'I used a Select Case because I think it is 
    'easier to read.
    Select Case grade
        Case "A", "B", "C", "D"
            'the += 1 is just a shortcut for
            'writing = passNumber + 1
            passNumber += 1
        Case "F"
            failNumber += 1
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid grade")
    End Select
    'You need to convert your Integers to Strings
    'so they can go into the Text property of your labels.
    lblFail.Text = CStr(failNumber)
    lblPass.Text = CStr(passNumber)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this code is the best solution for the OP. However, I think it would be worth pointing out why making `passNumber` and `failNumber` class level variables is what corrects the problem.